# how to access to a vector in the class from a function that belongs to that class in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

I am new in C++. I created a cpp and a header file. Here is the header file:

```
class LISCH{
public:                 
    class lisch_entry{
    public:
        bool valid;
        int link;
        int data;

        lisch_entry(){
            valid = false;
        }
    };

    vector<lisch_entry> data_vec;


public:

    LISCH(int);
    void insert(int);
    

};
```

In cpp file , i need to access that data_vec vector in insert function but i couldn't do it because it's my first time coding in C++. Here is the cpp file:

```
#include "lisch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LISCH::LISCH(int table_size){
   table_size=10;
   int x=5;    
}


void LISCH::insert(int new_data){
   
   
   
   lisch_entry entry;
   int add=new_data%11;
   if(LISCH.data_vec[add] == NULL) //here i need to acces data_vec
   {
       
   }
   data_vec.insert(add,new_data); //and also here

}
```

How can i manage to do that? I need to check if a specific position of the vector is empty or not.

Comment: `data_vec.insert` should work. If not, please create a [mcve]. `LISCH.data_vec` won't, use `this->data_vec` if you want to be explicit about it.

Comment: What is `table_size`? You just take the parameter, then assign `10` to it - then it's forgotten.

Comment: The vector is empty, `data_vec[add]` would exhibit undefined behavior for any value of `add`. Not sure what you mean by "check if a specific position of the vector is empty" - an empty vector has no positions, and it's not clear what it means for an instance of `lisch_entry` to be "empty".

Comment: I suspect that you want the constructor to construct a vector with `table_size` elements, like this `LISCH::LISCH(size_t table_size) : data_vec(table_size) {}` ? Also, the remainder operation should then be `size_t add = new_data % (data_vec.size() + 1);` - but what `add` is supposed to be used for, I have no idea.

Comment: "i couldn't do it " is not a problem description. Please include the compiler error in the question if you get any

Comment: Do you have a value in mind for an element that is 'empty'?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few of things wrong with code, probably for lack of planning or formulating the desired effect.

```
using namespace std;  // never do this in real programs. 
                      // Even some tests may fail accidently. 

LISCH::LISCH(int table_size){
   table_size=10;  // those are local variables, why assigning values to them?
   int x=5;    
}
```

`data_vec` is defined as a vector of `lisch_entry`:

```
   vector<lisch_entry> data_vec;
```

The  you out of blue access element of type `lisch_entry` with index `add`. Did you allocate that many elements already? It may not exist at all, the program would crash:

```
   if(LISCH.data_vec[add] == NULL)
```

An instance `lisch_entry` cannot be equal, cannot be compared to NULL as far as you had defined it. The check itself looks suspicious, what had you wanted to do?

```
  data_vec.insert(add,new_data);
```

`insert` receives an iterator as first parameter. An integer value isn't an iterator. An iterator of `add`-th element's iterator value is `data_vec.begin() + add`. It looks like have to check the documentation on `std::vector`.

You can find shorthanded documentation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

If you're trying to learn C++ on your own, this may be helpful: https://isocpp.org/faq